# Background Music for a Java game

Tags: java, audio

So I've been asked to help with a Java game and I've been given the Audio role. I get the audio to play but I need to get it to where I can stop the audio and start up a new audio string within another file that's calling it. Here's what I have;

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SoundTest{

// Constructor
public static void Run(String pen)throws InterruptedException {
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setTitle("Test Sound");
f.setSize(300, 200);
f.setVisible(false);       

try {
     // Open an audio input stream.           
      File soundFile = new File(pen); 
      AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);              
      Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

     clip.open(audioIn);
     clip.start();
  } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

and I have this that calls it

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.URL;
 import javax.sound.sampled.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

public class SoundCall{


public static void main(String[] args)throws InterruptedException {
JFrame f = new JFrame();

SoundTest sound = new SoundTest();
sound.Run("Jskee_-_I_Am_Pharaoh_.wav");

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"Window","Cracker",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
sound.stop;
sound.Run("Rejekt_-_Crank.wav");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, declare your Clip outside of the Run function, like this: `Clip clip;` then just do `clip = AudioSystem.getClip();` and finally, make a stop function in your SoundTest class that looks like this:

```
public boolean stop(int id) {
    if (clips.get(id-1) != null) {
        clips.get(id-1).stop();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Returning a boolean is for checking, so that your application is sure if it has stopped the  music or not. This is what your full SoundTest file will look like afterwards:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SoundTest{

private ArrayList<Clip> clips = new ArrayList<Clip>();

// Constructor
public void Run(String pen)throws InterruptedException {
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setTitle("Test Sound");
f.setSize(300, 200);
f.setVisible(false);       

try {
     // Open an audio input stream.           
      File soundFile = new File(pen); 
      AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);              
      Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

     clip.open(audioIn);
     clip.start();
     clips.add(clip);
  } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
 public boolean stop(int id) {
    if (clips.get(id-1) != null) {
        clips.get(id-1).stop();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

And in your SoundCall class, simply do

```
if(sound.stop(1)) { //1 is an id, I made it so that it starts at 1, not 0.
      System.out.println("Audio stopped.");
} else {
      System.out.println("Audio has not stopped.");
}
```

The id is when the clip was called, kinda. If it was the first clip to be executed, the id is 1, if it was the second the id is 2 etc.

Comment: where would I implement the declaration for my clip?

Comment: @Jotohooh At the top of your SoundTest file

Comment: @Jotohooh Edited the answer so you can understand it easier

Comment: many thanks, my program implements with ease into the project. :)

Comment: @Jotohooh No problem sir

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but now it has the problem that it wont stop playing the first clip, any idea on how to stop it?

Comment: @Jotohooh Sorry for the late response, but I edited the post to fit your needs even though you probably have fixed it by now, also this haven't been tested, so it might work and it might not. Just let me know.

Comment: i just got around to testing the code, the only problem i have been getting is with the ArrayList, other then that it works smoothly. Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, the problem was that I didn't import the ArrayList util